# Obtaining representations from characters in GAP

Tags: representation-theory, gap

Given a character $\xi$ in GAP of degree $n$, is there a way to obtain a corresponding representation with this character in the form that for every group element (not just generators of the group) one obtains an $n \times n$-matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IrreducibleRepresentationsDixon(<group>,<character>)`, which will return a representation (over $\mathbb{C}$) as homomorphism.

Note that the method requires some random-based searching, so runtime can be inconsistent. Also the representation is not necessarily given over a minimal field, or in any particular nice way.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a standard method in GAP to obtain the matrices for the regular representation (KG as a KG module) of a group quickly?

Comment: The command does not work in most examples for the regular representations. The error starts with #I  need to compute subgroup lattice
Error, could not find suitable elements? Is your command only for irreducible representations (as the name suggests)? I search a method that works for general characters that are not necessarily irreducible. My main interest is whether there already exists a command for the regular representation (which would not be hard to programm myself, but my feeling is that there should be an existing command).

Comment: Take the regular permutation representation and make matrices from them: `hom:=RegularActionHomomorphism(g);; maz:=List(MappingGeneratorsImages(hom)[2],x->PermutationMat(x,Size(g),Rationals));; rep:=GroupHomomorphismByImagesNC(g,Group(maz),MappingGeneratorsImages(hom)[1],maz);;`

Comment: Yes, this is intended for irreducible representations (since others are easily built from irreducible ones in characteristic zero).

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to obtain the matrices for the regular representation for all group elements and not just generators? It seems you commands just give the result for the generators.

Comment: Simply apply the map `rep`:   ImagesRepresentative(rep,groupelm);`.